# How to use bean in static method which is called by @BeforeClass test method

Tags: java, spring, junit, static, java-8

Let's suppose I have a test class `A` which extends from class `B`. This class `A` has one method with `@BeforeClass` annotation:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp(){
    createFakeData();
}
```

The method `createFakeData()` is in class `B` and its function is to create an object in database.

In order to do that, I have a bean in class `B`:

```
@Autowired
private DummyObjectsFactory dummyObjectsFactory;
```

And the content of the method `createFakeData()` could be something like that which returns a FakeData object:

```
public FakeData createFakeData() throws Exception
{
    return dummyObjectsFactory.createFakeData();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `@BeforeClass` method has to be static, that means that the `createFakeData` method has to be static too. But I cannot set that method to static because my bean `dummyObjectsFactory` will be always `null`.

How can I make my `createFakeData` method static avoiding my `dummyObjectsFactory` bean to be not null?

Comment: You have to create an instance of `B` somewhere. This has nothing to do with the question whether the method in `A` is `static`.

Comment: As I said, my class `A` extends from `B`

Comment: That’s not how you should create a unit test. But even then, nothing is stopping you from creating a new `B` instance inside `A.setUp()`.

Comment: If I try that, I still get my `dummyObjectsFactory` null

Comment: Perhaps, it’s about the steps needed to make the framework’s `@Autowired` processing happen. I don’t use Spring, so I don’t know the smallest setup to make this work, however, to me it feels like you shouldn’t bootstrap such a framework in a *unit test* unless really necessary. In other words, just instantiate the right type of `DummyObjectsFactory` needed for the test within `setup()`…

Comment: Please can you clarify how you are creating the spring context for your test, and how you are creating your bean of type B?

Comment: @Hedley, in order to answer you: in my test class `A` i have the following annotation `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)`, and in my TestConfig.class I have the beans which I need, for example `@Bean public FakeDataDao accountMonthData() { return new FakeDataDao(); }`. In my `TestConfig.class` I also have the annotations `@Configuration
@Import(DaoConfig.class)`, and in `DaoConfig.class` I have the dataSource I need to connect to my database. That being said, in my `A` test class, I have an `@Autowired
    private FakeDataDao fakeDataDao;`. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Holger in a way u are correct, we do use Spring quite a lot and we specifically prohibit `@Autowired` ( for rare cases) and insted only get these objects via a constructor. So, to me you are right, the setup if wrong

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not permitted in JUnit. However you can do some things for arrange it.

First, you can use **TestNG**, which allows to do exactly what you want.

If that is not an option, instead of using `@BefloreClass` annotation, you can use `@Before`. The difference between both is that `@BeforeClass` executes the method before all the tests while `@Before` executes the method before each test. If you use `@Before`, I would annotate the class with `@Transactional` in order to delete the data saved in the database.

In the end, if you don't want to execute the method for each test, you can use `@Before` and flat the call:

```
@Before
public void init(){
    if(!fakeDataCalled){
        createFakeData();
        fakeDataCalled=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to annotate your test class (B) with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` so that the autowiring happens correctly.

Take a look at section 15.4.4 in the [Spring Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/).
You can also just browse to that page and search for "RunWith"

Caveats:

1. I don't like static methods.  They tend to make unit testing difficult.
2. I don't like extending tests to make other tests.  I find it easier to make each test standalone and use composition for any shared functionality (i.e. make utility classes for shared test functionality that reside in the test source tree).
3. I don't like my unit tests depending on autowiring.  I mock all the dependencies and inject them with either reflection or the @InjectMocks annotation.